# cual es el mejor metodo para cargar un archivo excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

debo realizar una carga de un archivo excel (versión office 2010) a una base de datos sql server con un sistema creado con asp.net (c# vs2012)

he estado viendo en internet, y ya estoy algo mareado porque he visto una infinidad de métodos, pero no se por cual decidirme a la hora de intentar una implementación.
Según vuestra experiencia, que método es el mas recomendado?
angularjs?, epplus?, sheetjs?  algún otro que recomienden?

Saludos y gracias por leer.

Comment: es una carga que debes hacer por unica vez o es algo que necesitas controlar usando codigo ?

Comment: Mas alla de lo que dice leandro, (que si fuera por unica vez, no tendriamos dudas) esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones.

Comment: Que tal Leandro. gracias por tu tiempo. Es una app que debo realizar, la que aparte de permitir a un usuario subir este archivo, va a validar la data que contiene. asi que seria un proceso que necesito controlar usando codigo.

Comment: Independientemente de lo que uses para enviar el archivo de excel desde tu FrontEnd los datos de tu archivo deberian validarse en tu BackEnd y dependiendo de tus reglas de negocio generar tus errores, lo que puedes usar para leer tu archivo es usar officeopenxml.excelpackage

Comment: Hola LordOfLies, si, eso lo tengo claro, toda la validacion de los datos sera realizada en forma diferida por otro proceso (gatillado por otros eventos en otra aplicacion) mi tema aca es que como existen tantas formas de subir este excel a una base de datos, solo me interesa saber la opinion de gente mas experta en el tema. Al final, uno siempre mira tendencias a la hora de programar.. con esto busco, por ejemplo, evitar usar una herramienta que puede ser muy deslumbrante, pero que en el corto plazo, se queda obsoleta o sin soporte, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al tratarse de un proyecto web tienes dos opciones:

- OleDb, o sea acceder al excel como si fuera una base de datos
- Libreria a base de open xml

La eleccion depende del gusto de cada uno, pero hay limitantes, con oledb quizas publicar en web site que sean de 64bit tengas problemas, si puedes usa open xml

Podrias ayudarte con librerias como ser [ClosedXml](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki)

[Finding and extracting the data](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Finding-and-extracting-the-data)

veras como definiendo el range puede obtener un datatable con unas simples lineas

```
 var companyRange = ws.Range(firstPossibleAddress, lastPossibleAddress).RangeUsed();
 var companyTable = companyRange.AsTable();
```

el datatable luego lo pudes iterar, validar he ir insertandolo, o usar el [SqlBulkCopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.7.2), eso como guste

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios, como siempre, un excelente aporte para los que estamos aprendiendo. Saludos